# Is there a Java (Android) equivalent to VB6 Strconv

Tags: java, android, vb6, strconv

I have the following in an old VB6 class that I need to move to a Java class in Android.

```
tmp = StrConv(vValue, vbUnicode, AESLOCALE)

tmp = StrConv(vData, vbFromUnicode, AESLOCALE)
```

where AESLOCALE is 1033

I have had a hunt around but cannot seem to work out how to tackle this. 
Thanks

Comment: I have also been looking into this for a while. :D

Comment: what does StrConv do?

Comment: @Mosius In the instance of the question it just swaps between character sets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function

Comment: so you basically want to change the string encodong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to convert back and forth between English (Locale 1033 or ISO_8859_1) and unicode (UTF_16).

First, make sure you import the charsets:

```
    import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
```

For the top line in your question you can use this to encode a charset in UTF-16:

```
    //Convert to unicode/UTF_16:
    byte[] engilshBytes = myString.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
    String unicodeValue = new String(engilshBytes, UTF_16);
```

For the bottom line in your question you can use this to encode unicode in ISO_8859_1:

```
    //Convert to english/ISO_8859_1:
    byte[] unicodeBytes = myString.getBytes(UTF_16); 
    String englishValue = new String(unicodeBytes, ISO_8859_1);
```

---

Edit:

Link to the Android page on character sets (Works since Android 4.4):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets

Link to the Java page on character sets (NIO works since Java 7):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html